# JavaScript binding of function parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

Problem I am having is that when Yarn/NPM generate the code I see function binding changes. I have not seen anywhere on the style of binding

I have tried to check but could not find any documentation on it.

Here is a function defined in one of the files in the project directory named model.js

```
 export function buildModel(modelType, numTimeSteps, numFeatures) {..}
```

It is very clear this function takes in 3 parameters.
Now when I do a Yarn Build, this combines/rearranges all the js files & now when I look at the function it shows up like this

```
 const model = (0, _models.buildModel)(modelType, steps, numFeatures);
```

I do not understand this syntax style

Need details or resource link to understand this generated code style.

Comment: Those are not the same. The later will probably call the transpiled function shown in the first snippet. So therefore there is not much to understand, those are entirely different.

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm not sure I follow; it looks like some generated code to get at a property of an object (the leading parenthesized comma expression).

Comment: @pointy "now when I look at the function it shows up like this" ... thats not the function ...

Comment: @JonasWilms ah I see, right; it's an *invocation* of the function (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(0, _models.buildModel)` evaluates to `_models.buildModel`; it's a parenthesized *comma expression*. Thus the overall effect is

```
(_models.buildModel)(modelType, steps, numFeatures);
```

The `_models` symbol is I presume the object created during the build for symbols exported from that module. The code you're looking at is an invocation (a call) of the function, not its definition.

Comment: Any idea what the `0` is for ?

Comment: @HåkenLid See the duplicate which explains it properly

Comment: @HåkenLid right the linked dup explains it; it's to make sure the function is called "naked" with `this` bound appropriately; it's an arcane JavaScript function call detail.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the 0 is just there because the comma operator needs two operands and `0` is the shortest possible expression to put on the left hand.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it cleared my thinking, how come one does not see any literature on this!

Comment: @Integration well code transpilers have to do all sorts of things to ensure that code runs the way the source language implies that it should.